# Integer massive

Tags: java, integer

Please help. Why answer is "true true"?  How 053 can be equal 43 ? Thank you

```
public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = { 1,2,053,4};
        int b[][] = { {1,2,4} , {2,2,1},{0,43,2}};
        System.out.print(a[3]==b[0][2] );
        System.out.print(" " + (a[2]==b[2][1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the massive tag?

Comment: 053 is octal (base 8).  Which is 43 in decimal (base 10).

Comment: @StephenC The question is marked a wrong-duplicate. `a[3]` is `4` not `053`. And hence `4` will be equal to `4`

Comment: @UmaKanth - The question was about `a[2]` in the second print, not `a[3]`